# Problem: Partial View (PV) pages display right in single pages, not in page of four(4) PVs despite identical code. Need to pass parameter to PVs?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is the third question on this topic. Hopefully I’ve improved the question as I struggle with wrapping up this project. First, let’s look at the page with the Dropdown list of Alert_Identifiers—the key value that gets data from the mysql database for the project. AlertPick.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<edxl_cap_v1_2.Models.ContentViewModels.Alert>
@using edxl_cap_v1_2.Models.ContentViewModels

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "PickAlert";
}

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/capv1_2_refimp.css" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>

    <h4>Alert</h4>
    <div>
        @ViewBag.Message
    </div>

<style>
    tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: lightBlue;
    }

    tr:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color: white;
    }
</style>

    <table class="smallText">

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="elementInput">

                    <span class="smallText">
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Alert_Identifier) value
                        <input type="text" name="elementValue" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Alert_Identifier)" size="60" />
                    </span>

                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <text>&nbsp;&nbsp;</text>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form asp-area="" asp-controller="alerts" asp-action="_DetailsAlert" method="post" asp-route-id="@item.AlertIndex">
                    <input type="hidden"
                           name="Identifier"
                           value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Alert_Identifier)">
                    <input type="submit"
                           value="Check Alert">
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <text>&nbsp;&nbsp;</text>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="elementInput">

                    <span class="smallText">
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Alert_Identifier) value
                        <input type="text" name="elementValue" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Alert_Identifier)" size="60" />
                    </span>

                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <text>&nbsp;&nbsp;</text>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form asp-area="" asp-controller="infos" asp-action="_DetailsInfo" method="post" asp-route-id="@item.AlertIndex">
                    <input type="hidden"
                           name="Identifier"
                           value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Alert_Identifier)">
                    <input type="submit"
                           value="Check Info">
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <text>&nbsp;&nbsp;</text>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="elementInput">

                    <span class="smallText">
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Alert_Identifier) value
                        <input type="text" name="elementValue" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Alert_Identifier)" size="60" />
                    </span>

                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <text>&nbsp;&nbsp;</text>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form asp-area="" asp-controller="areas" asp-action="_DetailsArea" method="post" asp-route-id="@item.AlertIndex">
                    <input type="hidden"
                           name="Identifier"
                           value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Alert_Identifier)">
                    <input type="submit"
                           value="Check Area">
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <text>&nbsp;&nbsp;</text>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="elementInput">

                    <span class="smallText">
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Alert_Identifier) value
                        <input type="text" name="elementValue" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Alert_Identifier)" size="60" />
                    </span>

                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <text>&nbsp;&nbsp;</text>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form asp-area="" asp-controller="resources" asp-action="_DetailsResource" method="post" asp-route-id="@item.AlertIndex">
                    <input type="hidden"
                           name="Identifier"
                           value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Alert_Identifier)">
                    <input type="submit"
                           value="Check Resource">
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <text>&nbsp;&nbsp;</text>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="elementInput">

                    <span class="smallText">
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Alert_Identifier) value
                        <input type="text" name="elementValue" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Alert_Identifier)" size="60" />
                    </span>

                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <text>&nbsp;&nbsp;</text>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form asp-area="" asp-controller="EdxlCapMessageViewModels" asp-action="_Assemble" method="post" asp-route-id="@item.AlertIndex">
                    <input type="hidden"
                           name="Identifier"
                           value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Alert_Identifier)">
                    <input type="submit"
                           value="Add All">
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <text>&nbsp;&nbsp;</text>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Once the Alert_Identifier that corresponds to one record in the database is selected and the submit button is clicked, the browser opens this [page](http://starbourne.com/img/PickAlert.cshtml.jpg)

The first four rows work correctly when the “Check XXX” submit button is clicked. They show the individual data category “_DetailsXXX.cshtml” page one at a time. Here is the screen of the page showing the [_DetailsAlert.cshtml page.](http://starbourne.com/img/_DetailsAlert.cshtml.jpg)

This is set up so that these pages can be reviewed individually and the composite page, once working, will also work in the “Review” page and the “Approve” page. In the case of the “Assemble” page here, the four individual pages are intended to appear composited together when the “Add All” submit button is clicked, but currently these pages appear [without data values for the data items](http://starbourne.com/img/_Assemble.cshtml.jpg).

I am also going to ping a couple of more experienced people who have helped me previously to take a look at this, I am also studying a wholly different injection mechanism for injecting data into the program where needed which I will consider using in the follow-on specfications.

Lastly, I am [rexbroo](http://rexbroo@github.com) at GitHub.com where you can find nearly identical Visual Studio programs in the repos: edxl_cap_v1_2-VS4Win (for Windows) and edxl_cap_v1_2-VS4Mac (for Mac) and edxl_cap_v1_2,sql-mysql-VisualStudio where the most current dump of the database is 20180928.

Comment: Hi special request to @Shyju : I'd really appreciate it if you could look at this. I included my GitHub info and Links so you can get hold of any code you need for this. P.S. I'm open to adding the single pages one at a time to a composite page if concatention is a viable option. Thanks so much.

Comment: Hi @Shyju. I'm trying one more time. I edited the question to make it more clear. Not sure I succeeded. Still trying to pass `SelectedAlertIndex/Alert_Identifier to partial views on composite page. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input type="text" name="elementValue" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Alert_Identifier)" size="60" />
```

You don't need to use the @Html.DisplayFor  helper here. Just use:

```
<input type="text" name="elementValue" value="@item.Alert_Identifier" size="60" />
```

None of your input values should be using the Html.DisplayFor. That is inserting a tag into the value when all you really want is the value of the property.

Also, I question the reason for using multiple forms on a page. Could you use a single form and post to a single action? Do you need to post at all? Could the action be refactored into a get and let you use a `<a>` tag instead?

Comment: HI @Ryan Bennet. Each of the Emergency Data Exchange Language (EDXL) specifications (and this is first of seven) can be and are broken up into data categories that automatically align to discreet tables of the same name in the database. I chose to use that structure rather than stuffing them all in one long form page. This also helps to make the whole suite one datamodel. The XML-based specifications were developed in the last sixteen years. So, I'm not going to redo them. So I chose to use this structure for all specifications. .

Comment: Each EDXL specification will be an application that completed (by posting) becomes an emergency management message. The others are more complex than this one.  There are many design decisions I've made along the way over the last year and a half and I'd go blind trying to explain them all. I'm wrapping up the first project. I'll overcome this hurdle as I have the many previous ones maybe with your help? I can always make it one long form. I'm also trying to make it generic with few technology decisions, so I'm avoiding scripting langs though I include Javascript when I can't avoid it.

Comment: Hi @Ryan Bennett, Update: I changed the lines `<input type="text" name="elementValue" value="@item.Alert_Identifier" size="60" />` Thanks. Still stuck trying to get the `SelectedAlertIndex` parameter into each of the four partial views on the `_Assemble.cshtml` page.