# Need help passing 3rd parameter to 4 partial views on composite page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Need help passing 3rd parameter to 4 partial views on composite page.
For previous attempts seeking answer see  [here for effort with screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52487176/need-to-pass-parameter-to-multiple-partial-views-on-single-view-page) and [here for partial answers I’ve tried to use unsuccessfully)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52652910/problem-partial-view-pv-pages-display-right-in-single-pages-not-in-page-of-f) .

I’m persistent, but I’m still stalled looking for the correct way to pass a 3rd parameter for an `int Id` type of value in the lines `@Html.Partial("_DetailsXxxx", Model.Xxxx, ?)` to the 4 partial views in the `_Assemble.cshtml` page shown below:

```
@model edxl_cap_v1_2.Models.ContentViewModels.EdxlCapMessageViewModel

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_EdxlLayout.cshtml";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/capv1_2_refimp.css" />
    <title>Assemble EDXL-CAP Message</title>
</head>

<h4>Assemble EDXL-CAP Message</h4>

<!-- DetailsAlert -->
<div class="content-wrapper">
    @Html.Partial("_DetailsAlert", Model.Alert)
</div>
<!-- End of DetailsAlert -->

<!-- DetailsInfo -->
<div class="content-wrapper">
    @Html.Partial("_DetailsInfo", Model.Info)
</div>
<!-- End of DetailsInfo -->

<!-- DetailsArea -->
<div class="content-wrapper">
    @Html.Partial("_DetailsArea", Model.Area)
</div>
<!-- End of DetailsArea -->

<!-- DetailsResource -->
<div class="content-wrapper">
    @Html.Partial("_DetailsResource", Model.Resource)
</div>
<!-- End of DetailsResource -->
```

This parameter is an int for `SelectedAlertIndex` that results when the `Alert_Identifier` is selected from dropdown list in preceding `AlertPick.cshtml`page shown  below:
    @model edxl_cap_v1_2.Models.ContentViewModels.AlertViewModel

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "AlertPick";
}

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>

@{
    <h4>@Model.Alerts.Count Alerts</h4>

    <form asp-controller="Alerts" asp-action="PickAlert" method="post">
        <select class="cap_select" id="cap_select" style="width:100%;max-width:95%;"
        asp-for="SelectedAlertIndex" asp-items="Model.Alert_Identifiers">
            <option>Select one</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="PickAlert" value="Pick Alert to Assemble EDXL-Cap Message" />
    </form>
}
```

The `PickAlert()`controller code for this page:

```
public IActionResult PickAlert(Alert obj, int? SelectedAlertIndex)
    {
        if (SelectedAlertIndex.HasValue)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Alert loaded successfully";
        }
        return View(_context.Alert.Where(x => x.AlertIndex == SelectedAlertIndex));
    }
```

There are also controllers with similar code for PickResource,() PickArea () and PickInfo (), but I don’t use them in separate dropdownlists, but I wonder if the `Where` clause or something like it is needed for the 3rd parameter because it specifies  the respective XxxxIndex that equals the SelectedAlertIndex? Here  is PickInfo() for instance:

```
public IActionResult PickInfo(Info obj, int? SelectedAlertIndex)
    {
        if (SelectedAlertIndex.HasValue)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Info loaded successfully";
        }
        return View(_context.Info.Where(x => x.InfoIndex == SelectedAlertIndex));
    }
```

Comment: Is there any reason to not modify all partial views so they accept the model of type EdxlCapMessageViewModel which could contain the needed ID or any other Model which can contain all the required data?

Comment: Hi @VladL. As of now, each of the 4 individual partial views display correctly when accessed as a single view, and that is how I intended for the user to review the content. Note that each individual view starts `@model edxl_cap_v1_2.Models.ContentViewModels.Xxxx` and Xxxx is the model specific to the view (containing from 7 to 20 properties each). I'd be happy to modify the views if you can show me how that should be done without also causing the individual views to stop working.

Comment: Based on further research, I attempted to solve problem by adding 3rd parameter for ViewDataDictionary: `@Html.Partial("_DetailsAlert", Model.Alert, new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData) { { "SelectedAlertIndex", Model.AlertIndex }` for DetailAlert.cshtml, `@Html.Partial("_DetailsInfo", Model.Info, new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData) { { "SelectedAlertIndex", Model.InfoIndex } })` for _DetailsInfo, likewise for the last two partial views. I think this may be the right approach. Page compiles, but no data values for the properties [see screenshot](http://starbourne.com/img/_Assemble.cshtml.jpg).

Comment: Is there a way to combine `return View(_context.Info.Where(x => x.InfoIndex == SelectedAlertIndex));` with  `@Html.Partial("_DetailsInfo", Model.Info, new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData) { { "SelectedAlertIndex", Model.InfoIndex } })`?